# NDIS Intermediate driver interface to C#

Tags: c#, networking, driver, ndis

I'm developing what is essentially a specialized firewall application.  The solution needs to be 32 and 64-bit compatible.  My company wants to keep the current program interface, which is written in C#.

What I need is this: a way to monitor and manipulate all network traffic on the system.  My research has led me to believe that a NDIS (Network Driver Interface Specification) Intermediate driver is the way to go.  If I can write this kind of driver in C#, great, but I'm not sure that's possible.  At the very least, I need an interface in C# to a driver written in any language.

I found a great resource online for creating one in a series of articles entitled "Extending the Microsoft PassThru NDIS Intermediate Driver":

1. [Part 1 - Adding a DeviceIoControl Interface](http://www.wd-3.com/archive/ExtendingPassthru.htm)
2. [Part 2 - Two IP Address Blocking NDIS IM Drivers](http://www.wd-3.com/archive/ExtendingPassthru2.htm)
3. [Part 3 - Supporting Windows XP 64-Bit Edition](http://www.wd-3.com/031504/PTEx3_index.htm)

However, it is dated (2003).  Before I invest in reading and learning what it has to say, I want to make sure I'm not wasting my time.

Is there a better way to do this?  Are there any open source projects or articles that explain the process better than the articles above?  Am I even in the ballpark?  Help please.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly.  Are you trying to write the driver in C#, or do you just intend to use C# to interface with the driver after you would create it (using C++) ?!

Comment: @Miky: It doesn't matter.  If I can write the driver in C#, that would be great, but I'm not sure that's possible.  At the very least, I need an interface in C# to a driver written in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another page from the same author, titled [Windows Network Data and Packet Filtering](http://www.ndis.com/papers/winpktfilter.htm), which provides "a brief introduction to various techniques that can be used to filter network data and network packets on the Microsoft Windows platforms".

It mentions others options, e.g. "TDI flter driver" and "User-Mode Network Data Filtering", which may suit instead, depending on whether you *really* want to manipulate *all* the network traffic on the system.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to *manipulate* all network traffic, but the solution must be *able* to. This is not an option, it is a project requirement.

Comment: All traffic, or for example only all Internet Protocol traffic?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Sorry.  All IP traffic.  By all network traffic, I meant from/to any network device.

Comment: If you only need to filter IP traffic then a filter that's higher up the protocol stack (e.g. a TDI driver instead of an NDIS driver) might be better for you. The next question then is, can your filter be even higher than the TDI level: do you need to filter IP traffic seen by kernel-mode code (e.g. the file system implementation), or do you only need to filter IP traffic seen by user-mode code (e.g. Win32 applications)? Because in the latter case, a user-mode filter might suffice.

Comment: From this conversation, I'm finding I don't know a lot.  I'm not sure whether kernel-mode code would need to be filtered.  I need to catch any network communications of any program on the system, so maybe Win32 applications only?

Comment: You haven't said why you need to filter (except to say "specialized firewall application") so I can't guess or tell you what you need to filter. If you do only need to filter user-mode applications, that may be an easier job than writing a filter device driver that would run in the kernel.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be ambiguous.  I guess I'm just that clueless.  My requirement is that I must be able to *at least* intercept all web requests (http, https, etc.).  However, I will need to be able block certain other protocols and communications (like proxies, torrent, p2p, etc.) at some point as well.

Comment: Maybe you're right: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa504964.aspx says that an NDIS Intermediate Driver is recommended instead of a Firewall-Hook Drivers. *But* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa504969.aspx says that starting with Vista use "Windows Filtering Platform Callout Drivers" instead.

Comment: *sigh*  Ok, I guess I'll do some research and ask another question in a while.

Comment: One problem with drivers is that the driver architecture is less stable over the years: it changes more often than the Win32/user-mode APIs do, from one O/S release to the next. It's fairly stable but you're right that it can change over 5 years.