# What is the best way to make TCP and UDP packet spoofing and injection?

Tags: tcp, udp, code-injection, spoofing

Hy folks,

I'm kinda new to low level networking. I need to intercepts all TCP/UDP packets and potentially filter or substitute them with new ones.

What would be the best way to intercept these packets and inject new one? I'm only targeting  Windows platforms.

Comment: This should go to Server Fault.

Comment: This belongs here if he wants to write a program that intercepts packets. If he's looking for a tool, it belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Do you want to do this by using an existing tool/application which ha this functionality, or by writing your own device driver wich implements this?

Comment: I want to develop a program, not just use a tool.

Comment: [This question therefore doesn't belong on serverfault.]

Answer (score 2):

You want [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) if you're on Windows. What you're going to need to do is intercept (and filter) packets with WinPcap and then write a program that does packet creation when/if you want it.

Comment: I heard that WinPcap allows to capture packet, but does it allow injection too?

Comment: It doesn't, but the WinPcap about page lists a command-line utility (Nemesis) and an API (Libnet) for injection.

Answer (score 1):

Write a program that uses libpcap at [TCPDump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) contains tons of API for messing with low-level networking

Answer (score 1):

> I want to develop a program, not just use a tool

This page has some references to other pages which introduce the network device driver architectures: [NDIS Intermediate driver interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869947).

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like wireshark to intercept traffic.

If you planning to write a program which will do all this stuff , then you may need to go to driver level to intercept all traffic.

wireshark uses libpcap . I am not sure but that may help