# Block website without forcing user to restart browser?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, hosts

I know blocking a website is a popular question but [none](https://superuser.com/questions/128082/block-website-on-windows-without-host-file) of the answers I've seen address my particular situation:

I want to block a website (to be selected by the user, which must also have Admin rights, on Windows XP), **without** forcing her to restart her browser.

The well known technique of modifying the [hosts](http://accs-net.com/hosts/benefits_restrictions.html) file requires some browsers to be restarted. I want to accomplish that in a way that is browser-independent (e.g. Content Advisor works in IE but not in FF) and which doesn't require the user to restart his browser.

Please note that I am interested in knowing how to do this **programmatically**, so http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com aren't really the right places for this question, as they mostly suggest [tools and services](https://superuser.com/questions/47716/block-certain-websites-from-browser), while I am interested in the underlying knowledge so that I can implement it myself.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note that I am interested in
>   knowing how to do this
>   programmatically, so
>   http://superuser.com or
>   http://serverfault.com aren't really
>   the right places for this question, as
>   they mostly suggest tools and
>   services, while I am interested in the
>   underlying knowledge so that I can
>   implement it myself.

Such tools would filter traffic by implementing a [NDIS Intermediate Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557012.aspx). See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869947/ndis-intermediate-driver-interface-to-c).

Comment: Thanks for introducing the concept of NDIS Intermediate Driver to me.